# boto3 upload a string to glacier file

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-glacier

My workflow has a tar file downloaded from S3, expanded then I optionally want to upload it into a glacier vault.  Given there's other files in the S3 bucket, I don't want to use life-cycle management.  I have all this working under boto and am now slowly upgrading to boto3

I've recently discovered that rather than downloading into an on-disk file I can download into a string object and operate on it, which makes uncompressing a lot faster since I don't need to touch the disk.

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket,Key=path)
my_file = tarfile.open(fileobj=(StringIO(response['Body'].read())))
my_file.extractall(path="EXTRACTPATH")
```

If I want to upload to glacier via boto3, here's what I have:

```
glacier = boto3.client('glacier', region_name='MYREGION')
archive = glacier.upload_archive(vaultName='MYVAULT', archiveDescription=filename, body=response['Body'].read())
```

And that nets me:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the UploadArchive operation: Invalid Content-Length: 0
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you reading the same body twice? A `StreamingBody` streams from a socket, and so can only be read once.

Comment: Good call.  I stored the results from `response['Body'].read()` and then used it in the two locations and it appears to work.  Make that an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `StreamingBody` is a non-seekable stream, it reads directly from the socket so you only get one `read`. You'll need to save the bytes if you want to use them in multiple locations.